# How to adjust HTML table design

Tags: html

I have the following HTML, however, I will like it to appear like the image below but not sure how to proceed.

I want it to look like this:

How I want it to look

[image]

How it currently looks

[image]

Here is my code thus far and it looks like the second image I have linked:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;  
  border-collapse: collapse; 
} 
 
th, td {
  padding: 5px; 
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>Membership probabilities (%)</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>%s</td>
      <td>for x in calc2.prob:</td>
      <td>%s</td> 
      <td>%x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a Table in the following way

```
table, th, td {border: 1px solid white;  border-collapse: collapse; }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  }
    
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #799bab;
}  
  
  th {
    background-color: #2597cc;
  }
```

You can add the above code in the `<styles>`.

You can get more information about tables here - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @Robin Your asking for the color scheme and all?  The Code you had for the table doesn't look close to what you wanted so I thought you were having trouble with the table.

Comment: The table format is fine as I already know the logic, however, the design, color sheme from the image is what I need help in. I posted an image on how my code currently looks now, however, I want the color sheme to match the image I have posted

Comment: @Robin I changed it. check if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I attempted your suggestion however the table alignments are missing. The colors are shown but the lines that construct the tables are missing.

Comment: @Robin are you talking about the text alignment? The picture "How I want it to look" Has white lines in the table too. you can change it to black and see the lines of the table. ```border: 1px solid black;```

Answer (score 0):

Try This I hope you got your Solution .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Membership Probablities (%)</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>TWA</th>
    <th>BMPG</th>
     <th>TUCHOURA</th>
    <th>ABDor</th>
    <th>etc</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BAMG1</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
    <td>12.3</td>
    <td>79.7</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BAMG1</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
    <td>12.3</td>
    <td>79.7</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BAMG1</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
    <td>12.3</td>
    <td>79.7</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BAMG1</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
    <td>12.3</td>
    <td>79.7</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BAMG1</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
    <td>12.3</td>
    <td>79.7</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BAMG1</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
    <td>12.3</td>
    <td>79.7</td>
    <td>..</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```